# Is there a GUI application to view Sqlite databases on Android

Tags: android, debugging, sqlite

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android - viewing SQLite databases on device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2877567/android-viewing-sqlite-databases-on-device)

I'm wondering if there is an application out there that would let me view the sqlite database, my application created, in a visual context, other then using sqlite3 command from adb?

I'm thinking something along the line of sql server management studio, mysql workbench, etc...

It would have to have the following options:
- List tables
- Query tables
- View tables (data + schema)
- Create tables
- Drop tables
- Alter table schemas

Comment: Here is your complete answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2149438/tool-to-see-android-database-tables-and-data/4646473#4646473

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's certainly not management studio, but [SQLite Editor](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.speedsoftware.sqleditor) allows you to view and edit databases in place. You need root to use it, of course.