# View SQLite database on device in Android Studio

Tags: android, sqlite, android-studio

I am using the latest version of Android Studio. When I run my app on the emulator, I am able to view my database by going through:

`tools -> Android Device Monitor -> clicking on the emulator in the left panel -> file explorer -> data -> data -> com.project-name`

But this option isn't available when running my app on a device.

I have checked related questions:

1. [Android - viewing SQLite databases on device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2877567/android-viewing-sqlite-databases-on-device) The most voted answer here suggests copying the database to SDcard, and it's even for eclipse.
2. [Access sqlite database on android device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4856210/access-sqlite-database-on-android-device)

and these questions are from 2011 and 2010.
Are there any plugins I can use or other external tools?

Comment: "But this option isn't available when running my app on a device" -- correct. That has nothing to do with your choice of IDE. You can use **`adb shell run-as`** (see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14193376/115145) to your second linked question).

Comment: If You just want to look inside YOur database, You can download DB Browser from Playstore.

Comment: @Opiatefuchs I just downloaded DB Browser.How do i locate my database?

Comment: select "search DB" and type in the exact name of Your database...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [View contents of database file in Android Studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17529766/view-contents-of-database-file-in-android-studio)

Comment: The BEST solution was @Bob's answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19194576/how-do-i-view-the-sqlite-database-on-an-android-device

Answer (score 20, accepted):

## Connect to Sqlite3 via ADB Shell

I haven't found any way to do that in Android Studio, but I access the db with a remote shell instead of pulling the file each time.

Find all info here:
http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html#sqlite

1- Go to your platform-tools folder in a command prompt

2- Enter the command `adb devices` to get the list of your devices

```
C:\Android\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64\sdk\platform-tools>adb devices
List of devices attached
emulator-xxxx   device
```

3- Connect a shell to your device:

```
C:\Android\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64\sdk\platform-tools>adb -s emulator-xxxx shell
```

4- Navigate to the folder containing your db file:

```
cd data/data/<your-package-name>/databases/
```

5- run sqlite3 to connect to your db:

```
sqlite3 <your-db-name>.db
```

6- run sqlite3 commands that you like eg:

```
Select * from table1 where ...;
```

> **Note:** Find more commands to run below.

## SQLite cheatsheet

There are a few steps to see the tables in an SQLite database:

1. List the tables in your database:

   ```
   .tables
   ```
2. List how the table looks:

   ```
   .schema tablename
   ```
3. Print the entire table:

   ```
   SELECT * FROM tablename;
   ```
4. List all of the available SQLite prompt commands:

   ```
   .help
   ```

Source : [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18280430/3913366) SO answer..

Comment: it shows unable to open database..after the 5th step... :(

Comment: @Ben your device needs to be rooted in order for this work on a physical device. Otherwise, you must use an emulator such as the ones provided in Android Studio.

Comment: On Windows 10 I get for sqlite3 <your-db-name>.db : /system/bin/sh: sqlite3: not found - do I have to set some path variables for sqlite3, either?

Comment: @Ben  You may have to root your avd, and/or start adb as root at step 3 'root adb -s emulator-xxxx shell'

Comment: after 5th step sqlite is open in cmd, but not able type anything in command prompt

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to see realtime Database are:

#### #For **Android Studio 4.1 Canary 6** and higher

You can use a very simple Android Studio's feature [Database Inspector](https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/features#database-inspector). 
Where you can inspect, query, and modify your app’s databases using the new Database Inspector. For example, you can debug your running app by modifying values in your database and testing those changes on the device in *real-time* *without leaving Android Studio*.

To get started, deploy your app to a device running API level 26 or higher and select ***View > Tool Windows > Database Inspector*** from the menu bar.

#### #For **Android Studio 4.0 and lesser**

Use the [Android Debug Database](https://github.com/amitshekhariitbhu/Android-Debug-Database) library

[image]

- Android Debug Database allows you to *edit*, *delete*, *create* the **database** and **shared preferences** values directly in your browser in a very simple way
- Search in your data
- Debug Room in-memory database
- No need to root device

### **Using:**

---

### Add this to your app's build.gradle

```
debugImplementation 'com.amitshekhar.android:debug-db:1.0.6'
```

---

### Launch/Run app

---

### Find the debugging link in logs in LogCat

```
i.e. D/DebugDB: Open http://192.168.232.2:8080 in your browser
```

the link will be different and open it in the any browser

That's it Enjoy!!!

- If you are using it over USB, run `ADB forward tcp:8080 tcp:8080`
- Android phone and laptop should be connected to the same Network

For more details go to the [library](https://github.com/amitshekhariitbhu/Android-Debug-Database).

Answer (score 2):

There's a new native way on Android Studio 4.1 version called Database Inspector, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65773102/11443424) answer!

[image]

It will be shown in the bottom of android studio[image]

Comment: Please consider posting your answer as a comment

Comment: I'm sorry, but i don't have reputation enought yet :(, so i will make the answer more useful!

Comment: Thank goodness for this

Answer (score 1):

[This app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lastempirestudio.sqliteprime) is very useful, free and will remain free(Confirmed by the developer). Very easy to add, edit and delete.

It will work for rooted device and emulator. Also if you have DB file then 
you can browse it from SDCard of all devices including non-rooted.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Below is the simplest solution for viewing sqlite database in Android.

https://github.com/facebook/stetho

Steps to view SQLite DB

1) Add gradle dependency

```
compile 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho:1.5.0' 
implementation 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho:1.5.0' - for kotlin
```

2) In Application class

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
  public void onCreate() {
   super.onCreate();
   Stetho.initializeWithDefaults(this);
  }
}
```

3) Go to google chrome and type '`chrome://inspect/#devices`' to see connected 
   devices and can access SQlite DB.

Comment: Even in Java, it should be replaced to implementation now, not compile.