# How do I see database tables in Android Studio 3.1

Tags: database, android-studio

I have recently updated Android Studio to version 3.1. Afterward, I couldn't find how to view my database tables.

Answer (score 13):

You can use Device File Explorer:

View -> Tool Windows -> Device File Explorer

And find with its help your db among packages.

E.g. data -> data -> com.your.app -> databases

[image: screenshot from my AS 3.1]

Save it locally and open with any external tool like the [SQLite Browser](http://sqlitebrowser.org/).

Answer (score 0):

After Android Studio 4.1 version, we can use [Database Inspector](https://developer.android.com/studio/inspect/database)

[image: Accessing Database Inspector]